# How to add the release version to other files using the maven release plugin?

Tags: java, maven, version, maven-release-plugin

I am using the maven release plugin to release a project.
I would like to include the release version number in different files (for example the README.md and a resource property file).

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: you can use the standard mechanism for resource filtering and the ${project.version} property of maven as a placeholder. It will contain the release version during the build release-plugin creates.